# Why would belief in God (assuming God exists) with an untrue worldview count as belief in God to God?

Tags: theology, existence-of-god

Let's say someone believes says they believe in "you", but when asked about details they say you exist on a planet made of bubblegum, you are friends with these people you actually hate, believe in morality you actually hate, are a worm (a real reference to the Bible there), and they can't even recognise you in front of them.

Would you count that as belief in you to you? I wouldn't to me. However, I see many religious people perfectly okay to say they and especially other people they like believe in God just as divorced from what would be a reality if their God was true. Can this be justified?

By the way, this is why I think the question does God exists is pointless for these people to ask. A person without the world around them is not that person.

Comment: it's God, not "you".

Comment: @anon Think from God's perspective. This is focused on people who think it counts to God.

Comment: I don't think that we can think from God's perspective, idk. God is omnibenevolent, so you present a good argument for humanity and non-believers. yeah, I guess my point is more about human relationships being complex and not based on obedience and devotion.

Comment: @anon Every religion with obedience has God/scripture explaining God's actions. It is kind of hard to have a religion with obedience without it, as it makes grey areas a nightmare to figure out.

Comment: true. not sure if / how you are correcting me, so please go on if you care to? I think 'devotion' is key to the English language word 'divinity', form what (little) I know about theology etc.. cheers!

Comment: @anon One close example is with the Hindu dharma shastras. They seem to all ultimately come from one weird technically both deity (but not supreme deity) and human with no explanation for his motivations. Although the extreme difficulty is realizing it comes from him limits the possibilities.  The rest of Hinduism works on sanity logic though. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/50212/does-any-dharma-shastra-not-take-reference-to-manu-kashyapa-even-by-association

Comment: That's the very basics of philosophy: words are only loosely related to ideas. The same word can represent different ideas, and different people use different words to speak about the same thing. If someone say they believe in "God" but they don't believe the same facts about this god that you do, you simply don't believe in the same thing. That's why the question you really want to ask is not "do you believe in God?" but "what facts about god do you hold to be true ?"

Comment: I would say words slipping is not fundamental to all philosophy @armand isn't that linguistic idealism?

Comment: The grammatical errors makes it difficult to understand the question

Comment: @anon philosophy is about the invention, critique and analysis of concepts. You can't discuss concepts if you dont grasp how words relate to ideas.

Comment: @buraian yeah! Every second sentence can be interpreted ambiguously!

Comment: sure @armand but, nevertheless, we may not be linguistic idealists. i.e. may not think that belief in God depends on our language and how we phrase that belief. same as thinking that language is robust enough to communicate clearly with, even when we have different attitudes

Comment: I didn't struggle with it at all, I think. what phrases do you think are equivocal @Rusi-packing-up I'm guessing you're just struggling to find a "theory" which answers the question. to me, this suggests you don't have the answer, that's all

Comment: Start title: "God with untrue worldview?" Or "Belief(er) with untrue worldview?" And so on @anon 

Comment: I definitely see what you mean, but it's pretty obvious they mean "untrue belief in God by a believer" IF you read the question @Rusi-packing-up you have to follow arguments

Comment: @anon Its curious... I *actually* (first) read it as a God who believes nonsense. Then reading the whole post I found it so garbled I decided it may be either 

Comment: ha fair enough. I didn't write it so not offended. sometimes people try to cram a lot of different ideas into a small place for the sake of clarity; it doesn't always work @Rusi-packing-up

Comment: @Buraian I couldn't spot any. Vocative grammar is, in general, weird.

Comment: @anon, i dont see why you diverge about linguistic idealism. It's not what i am discussing. To illustrate, if a catholic like my grandma who thought god loves each human and therefore we all go to heaven, and a "fire and brimstone" fundamentalist protestant who thinks god will send 99% of humans to hell met and said to each other "I believe in God", it is obvious that, although they use the same words, they dont say the same thing, because "God" means something different to each of them. Belief in God do not depend on their language, i.e. they would believe the same even if they kept silent.

Comment: ok cool got it thanks @armand

Answer (score 1):

> they can't even recognise you in front of them... I see many religious
> people perfectly okay to say they and especially other people they
> like believe in God just as divorced from what would be a reality if
> their God was true

You seem to say that religion is based on pseudo [revelation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/divine-revelation/), and is in fact just a social relation of nepotism: and that this means they don't even believe in God.

> Many religions appeal to purported divine revelations in order to
> explain and justify their characteristic beliefs about God, and
> revelation has usually been understood as an epistemic notion

So e.g. Aquinas claimed

> An act of the will compensates for the “gap in the evidence”. However,
> since the activity of the will—when it comes to belief in God—is part
> of a reliable belief-forming process put in place by grace, the
> beliefs that it produces are warranted.

Surely then you would have to show more than a "gap" (we don't know their world is not made of bubblegum), but inconsistencies in belief, in order to argue that their belief about God (in his bubblegum world) are not justified.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with whether or not God exists. It is saying how can believing in a wrong God mean believing in the real one.

Comment: ok cool. do you want me to delete my answer? I didn't think it was off topic @AupakaranaAbhibhaa

Comment: Eh, probably a lot of people will make the same mistake, so just keep it to avoid them reposting this.

Comment: haha ok cool. nowhere did I say you did, tho I did assume you were talking about God's existence in general (see last sentence) @AupakaranaAbhibhaa

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept in psychology called the [persona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persona), which is the outward appearance or social role of an entity. Normally this mask represents how we intend to be seen. When we interact with others, we are generally interacting with their personas (created by them) using our personas (created by us). For entities not well known or not well understood, sometimes an extrinsic or other-created persona is substituted. In fact, inanimate things or ideas can be personified by giving them a persona of our making. Instead of interacting with their mask *of their making*, we interact with a mask *of our making* placed *onto them*. This relationship dynamic may be seen as similar to [parasocial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasocial_interaction), with overall positive [valence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_(psychology)).

If we assume that God is internal only, then the mask we give may matter less than our devotional experience. If our object of faith represents an axiom of pure love, for example, then the object behind the mask is perhaps pure [qualia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia). If, on the other hand, God is external only, then the concern presented in the question may be great, depending on God's personality and will. On the middle ground, where God is both within and without, then holding an erroneous picture within us may be living only halfway in blindness. Whether forgiveness or redemption is available depends on the system of belief.

Comment: broadly, thanks. needs more references though (may not be overly difficult to find them)

Comment: @anon -- My goal was to give a basic argument from reason, without getting into any particular religion or philosophy. Perhaps my post can serve as food for thought for other posters. Originally I was going to create a comment, but there was too much to be said.

Comment: no worries, I'm not criticising your decision.

Comment: But no one agrees on what the persona is either. Some people say he does this, others that.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa -- Indeed there is much disagreement on the *face* of God, if you will, but in the case where that entity is solely *internal* to the individual, one might argue that the object *behind* the mask is what matters, not how one dresses the mask. Say that to person x God represents love and life. In this case the object behind the mask could be pure emotional experience of love and life, pure qualia, without concern for semantic interpretation.